# Нужна помощь с запросом sql

Tags: sql, запрос, data.stackexchange.com

Нужно вывести на сайте https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new
Скoлькo людей имеют за любой гoд более 60 пoстов

Comment: Ну, наверное, надо сперва посчитать тупо для каждого юзера и года количество постов. Потом отобрать те записи, где оно более 60. И финально оставить только уникальные записи. PS. Но вот писать такой (достаточно несложный) запрос ВМЕСТО ВАС - это вряд ли...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как-то так

```
With [data] as (
  select 
    users.id, 
    Year(posts.CreationDate) AS [Year]
  from 
      users 
      inner join posts 
        on posts.OwnerUserId = users.id
  group by 
   users.id
   , Year(posts.CreationDate)
    having 
    count(posts.id) > 60
)
SELECT 
    [Year], 
    Count(id) As numberOfUsers
FROM 
    [data]
group by 
  [Year]
```